# How do I force a SVG to be contained in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to create a `<svg>` inside a `<div>`. I have used `overflow: auto;` in the `#display` rule, but the `<svg>` still goes outside of the `<div>`. I want the `<svg>` to appear only inside of the `<div>` as if the `<div>` is the display window of `<svg>`. When the `<svg>` goes out of the side of `<div>`, I want to put a scroll bar on the side of the `<div>` only. I appreciate the help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testbtm').click(function(){
        var str = '<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content"   style="position:absolute; left:800; top:800;">\
        <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
        <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>'
        var svgElement = $(str);  
        svgElement.children('text').text(1);
        $("#display").append(svgElement); 
    }); //end click 
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is add `position: relative` to your `#display`.

Since you have `position: absolute` specified, it will look for the closest ancestor positioned (non-static) element. Without `#display` being a positioned element, it takes the initial containing block, meaning the visible viewport as the anchor to position itself against. This is why you see the `<svg>` appearing to spill out of the `<div>`.

Of course, with your current inline styles, your hexagon would appear at the bottom right of the scrollable `#display`.

**Edit:** I have moved out the inline style to an external stylesheet specified under your class `.hexagon` as there seems to be an issue with displaying the number without moving the inline style out. Nevertheless, this gets you your result preserving your offset dimensions while keeping the `#display` scrollable.

Try out the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testbtm').click(function(){
        var str = '<svg class="hexagon ui-widget-content">\
        <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
        <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>'
        var svgElement = $(str);  
        svgElement.children('text').text(1);
        $("#display").append(svgElement); 
    }); //end click 
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
  position: relative; /* add this line! */
}

.hexagon {  /* extracted inline style to external stylesheet */
  position: absolute;
  left: 800px;
  top: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You gotta give `position: relative` to your parent element and your `left` and `top` values must be in `pixel`. `Reduced` width and `height` for convenience.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testbtm').click(function(){
        var str = '<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content"   style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%)">\
        <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
        <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>'
        var svgElement = $(str);  
        svgElement.children('text').text(1);
        $("#display").append(svgElement); 
    }); //end click 
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

svg{
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your SVG to be drawn inside the `<div>` then you will have to remove the `position: absolute` that you have set on it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testbtm').click(function(){
        var str = '<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content"   width="1000px" height="1000px">\
        <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
        <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>'
        var svgElement = $(str);  
        svgElement.children('text').text(1);
        $("#display").append(svgElement); 
    }); //end click 
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#testbtm').click(function(){
        var str = '<svg class="hexagon" class="ui-widget-content">\
        <text fill="black" x=75 y=75 style="text-anchor: middle">1</text>\
        <path d="M38 0 L113 0 L150 65 L113 130 L38 130 L0 65 Z" / fill="none" stroke="blue"></svg>'
        var svgElement = $(str);  
        svgElement.children('text').text(1);
        $("#display").append(svgElement); 
    }); //end click 
}); // end ready
```

```css
#display {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.hexagon{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="display"></div>
<button id="testbtm">test</button>
```

Here is fiddle goody for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hb796myn/